# How should I implement my Ruby code in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have small piece of ruby code that fetches news from a website that doesn't provide the facility itself. I would like to display the results in a view but I'm not sure where I should store the logic for the code i.e. helper, model (or lib)?

Looking for some guidance on the pros/cons of each and which choice is the most logical.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

news = []
domain      = ""
councilnews = Nokogiri::HTML(open(domain + ""))
councilnews.css('p.newsTitle').select do |article| 

    headline = article.text
    link     = domain + article.css('a').attribute('href').to_s
    content  = article.next_element.text 
    newsItem = {headline: headline, link: link, content: content}


    news.push(newsItem.to_json)

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, If you don't intent to store these fetched data permanently, just save these code as a `lib`, invoked by controller so the view can access its results.

Otherwise, you may consider to use them as a "service" for model using, that you maybe need to build a model to construct those data's structure and store them in database for further use.

It doesn't matter where you put those code in, a `/lib` directory? a `app/service` directory? both fine, this's just a convention. What really matters is how those code should be invoked and what role those code played in your business logic?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The only thing I will do with the result is display it in a view.

Comment: @Sheldon Ok, let controller invoke it to fetch data for views. Don't let view directly call it as a helper, it is not just a helper, it interacts with out-sourcing and should be considered as an extra action which belongs to controller level. More importantly it is better for testing.